# Error Code 3078 - Foreign Key not compatible - what does this even mean?

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep getting this Error code:

> Alter Table PAYMENT add FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId)REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CustomerId)   Error Code: 3780. Referencing column 'CustomerId' and referenced column 'CustomerId' in foreign key constraint 'payment_ibfk_7' are incompatible.   0.0010 sec

I don't know how to fix it. Please Help.

```sql
Create Schema IF NOT EXISTS AUTOMOBILE_COMPANY;

USE AUTOMOBILE_COMPANY;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CUSTOMER(
CustomerId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
CustomerFname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
CustomerLname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
CustomerPhone VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
CustomerGender VARCHAR(10),
CustomerYearly_salary VARCHAR(15),
CustomerStreet VARCHAR (30),
CustomerCity VARCHAR (30),
CustomerState VARCHAR(30),
CustomerPostcode VARCHAR(6),
ProductId INT NOT NULL,

PaymentId INT
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEALERS(
DealerName VARCHAR (10)NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
DealerBrand VARCHAR (7),
DealerModel VARCHAR (4),
DealerColour VARCHAR (5),
DealerAvailability VARCHAR (12),
DealerSalesByDate Date,
DealerCarEngine VARCHAR (17),
DealerTransmission VARCHAR (16),
DealerBodyStyle VARCHAR (20)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EMPLOYEE(
EmployeeSsn INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
EmployeeFirst_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
EmployeeLast_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
EmployeeBirthday INT NOT NULL,
EmployeeStreet VARCHAR (30),
EmployeeCity VARCHAR (30),
EmployeePostcode VARCHAR(6),
EmployeeState VARCHAR(30),
EmployeeSalary DECIMAL(6) NOT NULL,
EmplyeeSex VARCHAR(6)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PAYMENT(
PaymentId INT PRIMARY KEY,
Bank VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
CustomerId INT,
EmployeeSsn INT ,
Amount DECIMAL(7)NOT NULL,
PaymentDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
ProductId INT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PRODUCT(
ProductId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ArticleNumber VARCHAR (30)NOT NULL,
brand VARCHAR (7),
model VARCHAR (4),
colour VARCHAR (5),
availability VARCHAR (12),
CustomerId INT NOT NULL,
StoreId INT NOT NULL,
CarEngine VARCHAR (17),
Transmission VARCHAR (16),
BodyStyle VARCHAR (20)
);

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER ADD  FOREIGN KEY (productid) REFERENCES PRODUCT(productid); 
                                         
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER ADD  FOREIGN KEY (paymentid) REFERENCES PAYMENT(paymentid);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RENTAL(
RentalId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
RentalDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
ReturnDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
CustomerId INT NOT NULL,
EmployeeSsn INT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MANUFACTURER(
StoreId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Street VARCHAR (30)NOT NULL,
City VARCHAR (30)NOT NULL,
State VARCHAR(30)NOT NULL,
Postcode VARCHAR(6)NOT NULL,
ArticleNumber VARCHAR (30)NOT NULL,
SupplierParts VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS STORE (
StoreId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
StoreStreet VARCHAR (30)NOT NULL,
StoreCity VARCHAR (30)NOT NULL,
StoreState VARCHAR(30)NOT NULL,
StorePostcode VARCHAR(6)NOT NULL,
StoreManager_staff VARCHAR(30)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SUPPLIER(
SupplierParts VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
SupplierArticle_number INT NOT NULL
);

Alter Table PAYMENT add FOREIGN KEY (ProductId) REFERENCES PRODUCT(ProductId);
Alter Table PAYMENT add FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId)REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CustomerId);
Alter Table PAYMENT add FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeSsn)REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EmployeeSsn);

ALTER TABLE RENTAL ADD FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeSsn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EmplyeeSsn);

ALTER TABLE MANUFACTURER ADD FOREIGN KEY (ArticleNumber)REFERENCES PRODUCT(ArticleNumber);
ALTER TABLE MANUFACTURER ADD FOREIGN KEY (SupplierParts) REFERENCES SUPPLIER(SupplierParts) ;

ALTER TABLE SUPPLIERS ADD FOREIGN KEY (SupplierParts)REFERENCES MANUFACTURER(SupplierParts);

ALTER TABLE STORE ADD FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeSsn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EmployeeSsn) ;
ALTER TABLE STORE ADD FOREIGN KEY (SupplierParts) REFERENCES SUPPLIER(SupplierParts) ;

ALTER TABLE PRODUCT ADD FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CustomerId);
ALTER TABLE PRODUCT ADD FOREIGN KEY (StoreId) REFERENCES  MANUFACTURER (StoreId);

ALTER TABLE RENTAL ADD FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CustomerId);

ALTER TABLE RENTAL ADD FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeSsn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EmployeeSsn);

ALTER TABLE MANUFACTURER ADD FOREIGN KEY (ArticleNumber)REFERENCES PRODUCT(ArticleNumber);
ALTER TABLE MANUFACTURER ADD FOREIGN KEY (SupplierParts)REFERENCES SUPPLIER(SupplierParts);
```

Comment: Only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products.

Comment: Oh so sorry! Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to readd the correct tag, though, @KL.

Comment: That won't fix your issue, but you have a circular reference between `PAYMENT` and `CUSTOMER` -> `ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER ADD  FOREIGN KEY (paymentid) REFERENCES PAYMENT(paymentid)` and `Alter Table PAYMENT add FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId)REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CustomerId)` What is the point? The same between `CUSTOMER` and `PRODUCT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have posted has a few typo's/errors:

```
-- references "EmplyeeSsn" instead of "EmployeeSsn"
ALTER TABLE RENTAL ADD FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeSsn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EmplyeeSsn);

-- ArticleNumber is not defined as unique in PRODUCT, can be resolved by adding a unique 
-- constraint to PRODUCT on the column ArticleNumber
ALTER TABLE MANUFACTURER ADD FOREIGN KEY (ArticleNumber)REFERENCES PRODUCT(ArticleNumber);

-- Supplier parts is not unique in MANUFACTURER, it is the primary key of SUPPLIERS though
-- So this may be the wrong way round
ALTER TABLE SUPPLIERS ADD FOREIGN KEY (SupplierParts)REFERENCES MANUFACTURER(SupplierParts);

-- STORE contains neither a column called "EmployeeSsn" or "SupplierParts"
ALTER TABLE STORE ADD FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeSsn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EmployeeSsn) ;
ALTER TABLE STORE ADD FOREIGN KEY (SupplierParts) REFERENCES SUPPLIER(SupplierParts) ;
```

Once all of the above errors are corrected, your code does not through an error, and the foreign key on customer is created correctly:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dVrG7Re6r68jaqYJ8HfR4P/0

Answer (score 0):

From what I am seeing through your script you have 2 issues:

1st - You have a circular reference between the Payment and Customer tables. The Customer table is referencing the Payment table using the PaymentId foreign key, and the Payment table is referencing the Customer table using the CustomerId foreign key. You need to remove one of them so you'll eliminate the circular reference. If I were you I would remove the 1st one since you will most probably have multiple payments per customer but only one customer per payment. So keep the following script:

```
ALTER TABLE PAYMENT ADD FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CustomerId);
```

And remove this:

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER ADD  FOREIGN KEY (paymentid) REFERENCES PAYMENT(paymentid);
```

2nd - You are creating another circular reference when using the Product table because you are combining the product table with the customer and the payment tables twice. Here again you ideally would have a scenario where 1 customer uses multiple payments to pay for multiple products they are buying. So you don't need the following foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE PRODUCT ADD FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CustomerId);
```

The reason for doing is because you only need one key to build a relationship between two tables. With regards to the 2nd point, you don't need to create a reference between the customer and the product because is already inferred in the two previous relationships you created; that between the Customer and the Payment and the other between the Payment and the Product. So there is a chained relationship which correlates the Customer to the Product they bought.